# Insert a service function in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, function, service, woocommerce

Dear StackOverflow friends,
I have to insert a "service function" in Wordpress - Woocommerce that calls infos from a site to another one.

They left me some notes from the old webmaster and I need help to solve the puzzle. I tried to insert the function into a  tag but I don't know how to correctly integrate it in the php file.
I'd like to put this function in tabs.php that's a official and existing woocommerce page (I'll overwrite it with a folder in my template, no problem for this passage).

This is the note I received, the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var nf = $('.content_nutritional_facts');
if (nf.length) {
    var id = nf.attr('id');
    var url ="http://www.ourwebsite.it/__SCRIPT__NutritionalFactsService.php?          
sku="+id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            nf.html(data);
        }
    });
   }
 });
```

the file I want to put the code into is tabs.php (Woocommerce) and its content is

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}

$tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );

if ( ! empty( $tabs ) ) : ?>

<div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">

<!--start TRIED TO PUT HERE THE SCRIPT-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var nf = jQuery('.content_nutritional_facts');
if (nf.length) {
    var id = nf.attr('id');
    var url = "http://www.mywebsite.it/dropshipping/__SCRIPT__NutritionalFactsService.php?sku="+id;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            nf.html(data);
        }
    });
  }
});</script>
<!--end TRIED TO PUT HERE THE SCRIPT-->

<!--start TRIED TO PUT HERE THE html div-->
<div class="content_nutritional_facts" id="<?php echo ( $sku = $product-    >get_sku() ) ? $sku : __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"> something should appear     </div>
<!--end TRIED TO PUT HERE THE html div-->

    <ul class="tabs wc-tabs">
        <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
            <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>_tab">
                <a href="#tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>"><?php echo     apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', esc_html(    $tab['title'] ), $key ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?> panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
            <?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the [original tabs.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php)

Thanks for your suggestion and your time!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to achieve. Do you need to create a new tab, and that tab should pull data dynamically from another site? And I'm not sure it's possible to use ajax with a cross-domain URL, so I'd probably advise looking into [`wp_remote_get()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get)

Comment: Thank you @helgatheviking I'll look at your link... yes I'd like to create a new tab but what I'm trying to achieve and I'm not able to.. is to make something appear from that function (no worry for appearences now, only to verify that the script works and show text taken from the first website). Thank you so much, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to create a new tab and use `wp_remote_get()` to grab some remote content:

```
// Adds the new tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_nutritional_info_product_tab' );
function woo_nutritional_info_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Nutritional Information', 'your-plugin' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_nutritional_info_product_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}

// The new tab content
function woo_nutritional_info_product_tab_content()  {

    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $url = "http://www.website.it/dropshipping/__SCRIPT__NutritionalFactsService.php?sku=" . $product_id;

    // I'd suggest using the Transient API https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API to store the response
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url );

    if ( is_array( $response ) && ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $headers = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
        $body    = $response['body']; // use the content

        // do something with the response
        var_dump($body);
    }   
}
```